# JavaFX LoadException when passing value between controllers

Tags: java, javafx, authentication, fxml

I tried to make multi user login form but, I have a problem with passing value from one controller to another and I dont really know what is going on.

First controller

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    public Pracownik pracownik = new Pracownik();

    @FXML
    private Label isConnected;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPass;

    private Connection conn;

    // private ObservableList<Pracownik> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

        //   lista = new Pracownik().getAll(conn);
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent event){
        try {
            if(pracownik.isLogin(conn, txtUsername.getText(), txtPass.getText()) ){

                isConnected.setText("Correct");

                if(pracownik.stanowisko(conn, txtUsername.getText(), txtPass.getText()) == 1){

                    Stage primarystage = new Stage();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/BossView.fxml").openStream());
                    //BossController controller = (BossController) loader.getController();
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    primarystage.setScene(scene);
                    primarystage.show();
                }
                else {

                    Stage primarystage = new Stage();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/EmployerView.fxml").openStream());
                    EmployerController controller = loader.getController();
                    controller.getUser(txtUsername.getText());


                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    primarystage.setScene(scene);
                    primarystage.show();


                }
            }

            else{
                isConnected.setText("Błędne dane");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And second controller where i want to pass txtUserName

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class EmployerController implements Initializable {


    String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @FXML
    private  static Label imie;

    @FXML
    private Label nazwisko;

    @FXML
    private Label mail;

    @FXML
    private Label numer;



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        imie.setText(value);

    }

    public void getUser(String user){

        setValue(user);

    }

}
```

And this exception appears after trying to log in

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path
```

I found out that

```
 imie.setText(value);
```

cause this exception. Without it, everything is fine.

Comment: **Side Note:** The `LoadException` is rarely (if ever) going to be the root cause of your errors. Make sure you look through the entire stacktrace (the long list of errors thrown by the Java compiler) and find the lines beginning with `Caused by:`. That is where you will find the actual exception. In your case, I assume you'd see a `NullPointerException` (and it would point directly to the line causing the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable value is still null when called in the initialize Method of Employer Controller. In your example, you could just change your getUser Method like this:

```
public void getUser(String user){

    setValue(user);
    imie.setText(value);

}
```

Also, a method that is actually setting a value should not be called "get..." and it's most likely not a good idea to declare the Label static.